# Imageview to fit layout with border and rounded corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering if you could help me with something. I have a relative layout with an imageview at the top. Around the relative layout I have a border (layout_bg.xml). As you can see from the image I attached, the border doesn't continue around the image, which is what I want it to do. I know I need some extra code here but as I am quite new to java I haven't been able to figure it out or find a solution online, and I was hoping you could help me or point me in the right direction.

What I want to do:

Have the image fit my frame but with border and rounded top left and right corners.

**image**

[image]

#### layout_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<corners android:radius="8dp"/>
<stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#50A4A4A4" />
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

#### item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:geekui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="70dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView_player"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="225dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out code below, which make an ImageView have round corners on top-left and top-right.

```
public class TopRoundImageView extends ImageView {

    public TopRoundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public TopRoundImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private final RectF roundRect = new RectF();
    private float rect_adius = 7;
    private final Paint maskPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint zonePaint = new Paint();

    private void init() {
        maskPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        zonePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        zonePaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        rect_adius = rect_adius * density;
    }

    public void setRectAdius(float adius) {
        rect_adius = adius;
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        roundRect.set(0, 0, w, h + rect_adius);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.saveLayer(roundRect, zonePaint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(roundRect, rect_adius, rect_adius, zonePaint);
        canvas.saveLayer(roundRect, maskPaint, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory` `RoundedBitmapDrawable` classes like this

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable roundedDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable_resource));
```

To set the corner radius, do this

```
roundedDrawable.setCornerRadius(5.0f);
```

and then set it on your `ImageView` like this

```
imageView.setDrawableResource(roundedDrawable)
```

Click [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.html)
to learn more about the `RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory` class.

and [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html)
 for the `RoundedBitmapDrawable` class

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried the other code first, and since it worked i haven't tried this one yet but i do appreciate your help and quick response. Thanks!